# How to create variables with dynamic names in C#?

Tags: c#, string, dynamic-variables

I want to create a var in a for loop, e.g.

```
for(int i; i<=10;i++)
{
    string s+i = "abc";
}
```

This should create variables s0, s1, s2... to s10.

Comment: What language are you working in?

Comment: Please specify the context...

Comment: And your what's your question?

Comment: @cagin: +1 This is possible in javascript, I have never seen it in c#. I guess this possible only in scripting languages and not compiled languages. If your question was more specific, you would probably avioded the downvotes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create dynamic variable name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20857773/create-dynamic-variable-name)

Answer (score 11):

You probably want to use an array. I don't know exactly how they work in c# (I'm a Java man), but something like this should do it:

```
string[] s = new string[10];
for (int i; i< 10; i++)
{
    s[i] = "abc";
}
```

And read
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(VS.71).aspx

Comment: +1 Just for figuring out what the hell the OP was talking about.

Answer (score 4):

Your first example wouldn't work in any language as you are trying to redefine the variable "i". It's an `int` in the loop control, but a `string` in the body of the loop.

Based on your updated question the easiest solution is to use an array (in C#):

```
string[] s = new string[10];
for (int i; i< 10; i++)
{
    s[i] = "abc";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Obviously, this is highly dependent on the language.  In most languages, it's flat-out impossible.  In Javascript, in  a browser, the following works:

```
for (var i = 0; i<10 ; i++) { window["sq"+i] = i * i; }
```

Now the variable sq3, for example, is set to 9.

Answer (score 3):

You may use dictionary.
Key - dynamic name of object
Value - object

```
        Dictionary<String, Object> dictionary = new Dictionary<String, Object>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            //create name
            string name = String.Format("s{0}", i);
            //check name
            if (dictionary.ContainsKey(name))
            {
                dictionary[name] = i.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                dictionary.Add(name, i.ToString());
            }
        }
        //Simple test
        foreach (KeyValuePair<String, Object> kvp in dictionary)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Key: {0} - Value: {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value));
        }
```

Output:

```
Key: s0 - Value: 0
Key: s1 - Value: 1
Key: s2 - Value: 2
Key: s3 - Value: 3 
Key: s4 - Value: 4
Key: s5 - Value: 5
Key: s6 - Value: 6
Key: s7 - Value: 7
Key: s8 - Value: 8
Key: s9 - Value: 9
Key: s10 - Value: 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Use some sort of `eval` if it is available in the language.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the language.

Commonly when people want to do this, the correct thing is to use a data structure such as a hash table / dictionary / map that stores key names and associated values.