# Create dynamic variable name

Tags: c#

Can we create dynamic variable in C#?

I know my below code is threw error and very poor coding. But this code have small logic like create dynamic variable

```
var name=0;
for(i=0;i<10;i++)// 10 means grid length
{
    name+i=i;
}

var xx1=name1;
var xx2=name2;
var xx3=name3;
```

> Is it possible in c#? Create dynamic variable in c#? and change the variable name in c#? and concatenate the variable name in c#(*like we can concatenate any control id or name*)...

**Why I need the dynamic variable name (scenario):**

```
var variablename=""
var variablename0=No;
var variablename1=Yes;
var variablename2=No;
```

.
.
.

I have a `gridview` with multiple rows. And I need assign server side variable to every row. So I need set of variables in server side. the only I can set `Text=<%# variablename+rowCount%>` for every template field.

This `rowCount` means every grid row index.

If the grid has 2 rows, Then `rowCount` values are 0,1,2

Now I need to change the `variablename` to `variablename0,variablename1,variablename2` dynamically for separate row.

Comment: If you ask a question with specific `c#` version, you should add it only. If you ask a question with general `c#`, just `c#` tag will be enough.

Comment: @MichaC :) I don't need arrays.

Comment: After long time now I got it can possible in angularjs.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

C# is strongly typed so you can't create variables dynamically.  You could use an array but a better C# way would be to use a Dictionary as follows.  More on [C# dictionaries here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace QuickTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary<string, int> names = new Dictionary<string,int>();


            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                names.Add(String.Format("name{0}", i.ToString()), i);
            }

            var xx1 = names["name1"];
            var xx2 = names["name2"];
            var xx3 = names["name3"];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 from me. Is it possible without using `Dictionary` ?

Comment: @RameshRajendran, I think you need to think of this problem more abstractly. A variable, by definition, is a *key* that has a *value*--thus a `Dictionary` for variables that can't be declared at compile-time is the appropriate data structure.

Comment: @Michael Your definition of variable has helped me to understand that the absence of dynamic variables in C# is not a disadvantage because we can use the Dictionary instead.  :)

Comment: I used this method. It's okay for single variables such as int, long, object, etc...However, integrating List<something> as a dictionary element causes tremendous slowness.

Answer (score 17):

No. That is not possible. You should use an array instead:

```
name[i] = i;
```

In this case, your `name+i` is `name[i]`.

Answer (score 4):

Variable names should be known at compile time. If you intend to populate those names dynamically at runtime you could use a `List<T>`

```
 var variables = List<Variable>();
 variables.Add(new Variable { Name = inputStr1 });
 variables.Add(new Variable { Name = inputStr2 });
```

here input string maybe any text or any list

Answer (score 3):

try this one, user json to serialize and deserialize:

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

    namespace ConsoleApplication1
    {
       public class Program
       {
          static void Main(string[] args)
          {
              object newobj = new object();

              for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
              {
                List<int> temp = new List<int>();

                temp.Add(i);
                temp.Add(i + 1);

                 newobj = newobj.AddNewField("item_" + i.ToString(), temp.ToArray());
              }

         }

     }

      public static class DynamicExtention
      {
          public static object AddNewField(this object obj, string key, object value)
          {
              JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

              string data = js.Serialize(obj);

              string newPrametr = "\"" + key + "\":" + js.Serialize(value);

              if (data.Length == 2)
             {
                 data = data.Insert(1, newPrametr);
              }
            else
              {
                  data = data.Insert(data.Length-1, ","+newPrametr);
              }

              return js.DeserializeObject(data);
          }
      }
   }
```

Comment: This is super slow, not even talking about multithreading can cause some conflict while de/serialize.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, it will give you a compile time error,

You can use array for this type of requirement .

For your Reference :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx