# Can we create variables at run time

Tags: c#, windows

In c# why is it not allowing to create variable names dynamically? I am trying something like this:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < ceoList.Count; i++)
 {
      List<VP> "vp" + i = new List<VP>();                   
 }
```

I want to generate variable names at run time. Like `"vp" + i` here.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20857773/590783

Comment: You can do this sort of stuff in perl and python, but you correctly chose to use C# to avoid this kind of stuff.

Comment: Why would you ever need to do this? You wouldn't really have access the the variable at runtime any.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to create variable names at run time, you want to create data structures.

```
 List<List<VP>> vps = new List<List<VP>>

 for (int i = 0; i < ceoList.Count; i++)
            {
                vps.Add( new List<VP>());
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to accomplish is not a valid programming syntax, and will not compile in any imperative programming language compiler!

What you want is a way to name references to a set of objects of the type List, so to achieve that I would recommend you to check it out HashTables in the namespace System.Collections.

> Hashtable vpTable = new Hashtable();
>
> for (int i = 0; i < ceoList.Count; i++)
>
> {
>
> vpTable.add("vp" + i, new List());
>
> }