# How do I Reference a Global variable with two Concatenated variables/strings (Visual Basic)

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have to make reference more that a hundred variables in if statements, I could just type them all out, but is there a way that i can combine two variables X and a number and use that to reference a variable? In other words can i use a string to reference a variable?

Comment: You'll need to use Reflection probably to do such a thing. But that shouldn't be required for normal problems. You may want to rethink your approach to solving the problem.

Comment: You could switch to an array.

Answer (score 0):

Use Dictionary. Where key is a string: your variable name. 
And value is the value assigned to it.

Take a look at the answer to this:
[Create dynamic variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20857773/create-dynamic-variable-name)