# Naming a variable based on another variable

Tags: c#, variables

Sorry if this is a duplicate, but I didn't find what I need (over 30 minutes of searching the web)

I want to create variable with name from other variable (string)
Is there a possibility to do this in c#?
I'm new to c#.

Comment: Why would you need to change a variable name at runtime?

Comment: What have you tried?  How are you going to use this dynamically-named variable?  You might be better off using a collection of some sort.

Comment: I usually use a Dictionary for that kind of thing. You'll need to explain your use case better if you expect help.

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20857773/create-dynamic-variable-name

Comment: I don't need dynamicly-named variable. I just want to set it's name from other

Comment: I like the idea of a `Dictionary` for this.  My wife had to do something similar in Java, so I had her use a `Hashmap`, which works similarly.

Comment: @Pawiczekk You just said "I don't need X. All I need is X!".

Comment: @Luaan I said that I want to create variable but I don't need changing it's name to other than from this variable

Comment: There are some (very old language, several xBase dialects) which allow such constructs. But we old ones used this feature as a replacement for arrays ... and tried to coop with the problems we faced from this ugly hacks. C# will hopefully NEVER allow this - and before someone yells at me: I know there is the dynamic type ....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't, and it makes no sense honestly to have a feature like that.

If you want , you can use a dictionary, where you can have the key be a string:

```
 Dictionary<string, RectangleShape> shapes = new Dictionary<string, RectangleShape>();
    shapes.Add("nameTheKey", new RectangleShape( ... ));
```

Then you can simply read the "variable" like

```
shapes["nameTheKey"]
```

Answer (score 2):

No, and it doesn't make any sense.

Variable (or more precisely, *local*) names are only important at compile-time, and they only have values at runtime. If you add a new variable, you'd also need to add code to handle that variable - but how do you write and use that code without the compiler?

However, if you simply want to store some data in a key-value fashion, you can use a dictionary:

```
var data = new Dictionary<string, decimal>();
```

The first type argument is the key, and the second is the value. Do note that the values all have to be of the same type, or a type that derives from some common type.

If you want something more like JavaScript, you can have a look at the dynamic features of C# (`dynamic`, `ExpandoObject`, ...) - but frankly, you'll be better off adopting the idioms of C# 99% of the time.

`ExpandoObject` allows you to use code like this:

```
dynamic item = new ExpandoObject();
((IDictionary<string, object>)item)["Message"] = "Hi!";

Console.WriteLine(item.Message);
```

But again, it's rarely the best way to do something :)