# c# give name to Queue() made by a foreach loop

Tags: c#, queue

There is anyway to gives the queue id name? (0,1,2 and so on):

```
foreach (var item in FirstLineKeyValuePairs)
{

    Queue *name* = new Queue());

}
```

i want the give name to the new Queue().

Comment: It's likely you want to have an array of `Queue`s if you want to assign a number to them.

Comment: The real question is why do you care about that ? What is the problem all of the queue in the loop to have same name ? What is the real problem which you are facing.

Comment: I think he is looking for something like "dynamic variable naming" what was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20857773/create-dynamic-variable-name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily achieve this with an array or a list of queues:

```
var queues = new List<Queue>();
foreach (var item in FirstLineKeyValuePairs)
{    
    queues.Add(new Queue());
}
```

Now you can access them by an index:

```
var q1 = queues[0];
```

This is not the exact thing you want, but usually you don´t care for variable-names and want only *access* the data of any variable. You don´t need its "name" for that as shown above.

Comment: maybe he wants to work with `nameof()` for exception handling or something - that's the situation I heard that question mostly