# How to set value by call variable name from string c#

Tags: c#, arrays, crystal-reports

Now I'm new for c# development.

I have 100 data from Array and also have 100 variables.

How can I match 100 data with 100 variables?

for example

```
for(int count = 0 ; count < array.lenght ; count++)
{
    Var+count = array[count];
}
```

Something like this.

or you guy have another solution please help me. I don't want to do like

set  Var1 to Var100 by hand.

More Information 
   Actually I need to add the arrays values to text object in CrystalReport

For example if I want to add the value

```
 TextObject txtLot1 = (TextObject)report.ReportDefinition.Sections["Section4"].ReportObjects["txtLot1"];

 txtLot1.Text = Arrays[i]
```

something like this. so , I try to use dictionary but I don't think it will work.

Comment: You are having an array, Then why are you going for 100 separate variables? access the values using its index, like what you are doing for assignment(`array[count]`)

Comment: If you need a specific key to retrieve a specific value, you should look at turning your array into a Dictionary<string, int>

Comment: I'm honestly not quite sure what your use case is. C# does not allow you to arbitrarily create and reference variables at runtime with names that are not pre-determined. That's why arrays/lists/dictionaries/etc exist.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create dynamic variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20857773/create-dynamic-variable-name)

Comment: This is almost certainly an X/Y problem. What are you actually *trying to do* here? The code is the "how you're currently trying to do it", which is not quite the same thing (especially for X/Y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of doing what you are asking for on the fly with a `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`, all keys in a dictionary must be unique, but since you are appending 1 to each key in your loop this will suffice:

```
Dictionary<string, int> myKeyValues = new Dictionary<string, int>();

for(int count = 0 ; count < array.length; count++)
{
    //Check to make sure our dictionary does not have key and if it doesn't add key
    if(!myKeyValues.ContainsKey("someKeyName" + count.ToString())
    {
         myKeyValues.Add("someKeyName" + count.ToString(), count);
    }
    else
    {
        //If we already have this key, overwrite, shouldn't happen as you are appending a new int value to key each iteration
        myKeyValues["someKeyName" + count.ToString()] = count;
    }
}
```