# Variable in variable name

Tags: c#, object, dynamic

I need to make a loop and in this I need to change the properties of the buttons.
What I have made:

```
while(count>=1){
P+count.BackColor = Color.Blue;
}
```

Result I want:

```
P1.BackColor = Color.Blue;
P2.BackColor = Color.Blue;
P3.BackColor = Color.Blue;
etc..
```

ps: the colors need to be specifically the colors form the database so I can't set them like the result.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: The programming language is C#

Comment: Isnt it possible for you to use a Map?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create dynamic variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20857773/create-dynamic-variable-name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all controls in form and check if control is button or not. If control is a button then change background color. You can use code below,

```
foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
{
     if(control.GetType() == typeof(Button))
     {
            ((Button)control).BackColor = Color.Red;
     }
}
```