# C# WPF using string to access TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, string, textbox

So I have 10 textboxes called `TextBox1` -> `TextBox10`

Is it possible to write a for loop, create a string `TextBox + i`
and use that String to set the text of the textboxes?

Comment: Try using FrameworkElement.FindName(string) method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create dynamic variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20857773/create-dynamic-variable-name)

Answer (score 1):

As @npap mentioned you can use `FrameworkElement.FindName(string)`.

Somewhere in xaml:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Name="Textbox1"/>
    <TextBox Name="Textbox2"/>
    <TextBox Name="Textbox3"/>
    <TextBox Name="Textbox4"/>
    <TextBox Name="Textbox5"/>
    <TextBox Name="Textbox6"/>
    <TextBox Name="Textbox7"/>
    <TextBox Name="Textbox8"/>
    <TextBox Name="Textbox9"/>
    <TextBox Name="Textbox10"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Code behind:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace YourWpfApp
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LoopOverTextBoxes();
        }

        private void LoopOverTextBoxes()
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                var textbox = (TextBox)FindName($"Textbox{i}");
                textbox.Text = $"Name of this textbox is {textbox.Name}";
            }
        }
    }
}
```