# How can I declare a string variable with my name + adding my birth month as a number?

Tags: c#

I was wondering how can I declare a string variable with my name adding my birth month as a number on it. IF I CAN. 
I'm not coding so I only have to know if I can do it or not, but if it is possible show me how.

Comment: Most likely you can do it only if you're using something like `Reflection.Emit`... But why do you want to achieve that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create dynamic variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20857773/create-dynamic-variable-name)

Comment: you want something like `$"{myName}{birthMonth}"` or what?

Comment: @Fabjan - it was a question in on of my exams before. So I'm being ready if accidentally my profesor will post it the same question. So I haave to know if it is possible for a begginer, it is a provocative question.

Comment: @Joooohn Well, C# is a strongly typed language so unless you're using some hacks - you can't

Comment: You have to clarify exactly what you mean. Most of the comments and answers are probably way over-thinking it. I suspect your teacher was looking for something very simple like `string nameMonth = "Jooooon" + birthMonth.ToString();`

Answer (score 0):

If this items are in a class, you could do ToString() method like this:

```
public override ToString()
{
   return string.Format("{0}, {1}", this.Name, this.BirthdayMonth);
}
```

then when you do a Writeline for example you can do

```
Console.WriteLine(person.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a Person class that encapsulates a person's last name, first name and birthday.

```
public class Person 
{

  public DateTime BirthDay {get;}
  public string LastName {get;}
  public string FirstName {get;}

  public Person(string lastName,  string firstName, DateTime birthDay) => (LastName, FirstName, BirthDay) = (lastName, firstName, birthDay);

  public override string ToString() => $"{FirstName} {LastName} {BirthDay.Month}";
}
```

And call ToString to get the result that you want.